# Translate javascript to angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to AngularJS and still don't have much experience in it, so I have a javascript here that I want to translate to AngularJs.
I would like to get the id from the list using angularjs.

This is my python list:

```
MissionNameList =  [{'id':'1','name':'Alabama'},{'id':'2','name': 'Alaska'}]
```

This is my html:

```
<input type="text"
     id={{ thisName }}
     ng-model="selected"i
     ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode)"
     typeahead="mission as mission.name for mission in missionNameList | filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:8"
     name={{ missionname }}
     disabled>
     {{ missiontitle }}

<input type="hidden"
     id={{ thisId }}
     name="{{ field.name }}"
     value="{{field.value}}">
```

Right now I am using pure javascript, but instead of javascript I would like to use AngularJs, is there any way I could get the same result using AngularJs? Thank you.

This is my script:

```
    var missionName = document.getElementById('missionName');
    var missionId = document.getElementById('missionId');

    var nameList = {{ MissionNameList|safe }}

    missionName.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        var value = e.target.value;

        for(var i=0; i<nameList.length; i++){
            var name = nameList[i].name;

            if(name == value) {
                missionId.value = nameList[i].id;
                break;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: are you try something? what you try do here `var nameList = {{ MissionNameList|safe }}`?

Comment: Put your html code also. According to my understanding missionName & missionId are input type text element. right ?

Comment: Here is the edited codes.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you get one **input** DOM element and you add a listener 'keyup' to it.

On 'keyup' you want to get the input's value , you read an array and assign new value to your '**missionId**' element.

**In angularjs** we manipulate **DOM elements** into **Directives**:

You can do that with a directive like this, but it would be better to read the doc:

```
.directive('myField', function($log, $http, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        nameList: '=',//pass the array from controller

      },
      templateUrl: 'mytemplate.tpl.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind("keyup", function () {
                //something here  , like read your array                  
            });
      }

    }
  });
```